# How to reload page on a Cordova project?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, firebase

I am building an app, using [polymer starter kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit) & [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) to wrap the project. Now, since I use [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) as a database for storing data, I ended up using two native firebase javascript function to find user data:

getAuth()

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
var authData = ref.getAuth();
if (authData) {
  console.log("Authenticated user with uid:", authData.uid);
}
```

onAuth()

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    console.log("Authenticated with uid:", authData.uid);
  } else {
    console.log("Client unauthenticated.")
  }
});
```

Those two functions require a reload to bring back data from firebase, but :

```
window.location.reload();
```

doesn't work

Alos looked for a Cordova plugin: [webview-reloader](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.malex.cordova.plugin.webview-reloader), installed it but redirect and reload still not working.

When i use the reload() function the screen of my android phone is going white and the application stop working. Need to close the app and open it again.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `document.location = 'index.html'`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8506527

Comment: Did try document.location = 'index.html' and that throw an error, saying that he canno't find the file location

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since Cordova is a wrapper around a browser window:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

It works for the browser windows as well as a Cordova app.

Comment: No, this does not reloads anything — Failed to load webpage with error: Frame load interrupted

Comment: Could you provide some example code to illustrate why it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Here an example — window.location.reload()

Comment: This won't work if you use something like angular which does html5 push state routing; the URL the page thinks it is will have changed.

Answer (score 9):

This works for iOS and Android (at least with 2016 platform versions).

```
// keep startup url (in case your app is an SPA with html5 url routing)
var initialHref = window.location.href;

function restartApplication() {
  // Show splash screen (useful if your app takes time to load) 
  navigator.splashscreen.show();
  // Reload original app url (ie your index.html file)
  window.location = initialHref;
}
```

Comment: Still works today for our React cordova app. Thank you

Comment: What if I just want to refresh the current webpage on Cordova app?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.cordovaService) { // is cordova
    this.window.location.href = `${this.window.location.protocol}//${this.window.location.host}`;
} else {
    this.window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing / accepted answers.