# Location.reload() on mobile JS app

Tags: javascript, mobile, reload, desktop

On a desktop, you can use `location.reload();` and it will reload the page, restarting the code on it.

But what if I wanted to 'reload' a javascript app? Is there a way to do so? Thanks!

```
location.reload();
// Page reloads on desktop, app does nothing on mobile
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [534 different ways](http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html) to reload a page in JavaScript. Take your pick:

```
location = location
location = location.href
location = window.location
location = self.location
location = window.location.href
location = self.location.href
location = location['href']
location = window['location']
location = window['location'].href
location = window['location']['href']
location = window.location['href']
location = self['location']
location = self['location'].href
location = self['location']['href']
location = self.location['href']
location.assign(location)
location.replace(location)
window.location.assign(location)
window.location.replace(location)
self.location.assign(location)
self.location.replace(location)
location['assign'](location)
location['replace'](location)
window.location['assign'](location)
window.location['replace'](location)
window['location'].assign(location)
window['location'].replace(location)
window['location']['assign'](location)
window['location']['replace'](location)
self.location['assign'](location)
self.location['replace'](location)
self['location'].assign(location)
self['location'].replace(location)
self['location']['assign'](location)
self['location']['replace'](location)
location.href = location
location.href = location.href
location.href = window.location
location.href = self.location
location.href = window.location.href
location.href = self.location.href
location.href = location['href']
location.href = window['location']
location.href = window['location'].href
location.href = window['location']['href']
location.href = window.location['href']
location.href = self['location']
location.href = self['location'].href
location.href = self['location']['href']
location.href = self.location['href']
location.assign(location.href)
location.replace(location.href)
window.location.assign(location.href)
window.location.replace(location.href)
self.location.assign(location.href)
self.location.replace(location.href)
location['assign'](location.href)
location['replace'](location.href)
window.location['assign'](location.href)
window.location['replace'](location.href)
window['location'].assign(location.href)
window['location'].replace(location.href)
window['location']['assign'](location.href)
window['location']['replace'](location.href)
self.location['assign'](location.href)
self.location['replace'](location.href)
self['location'].assign(location.href)
self['location'].replace(location.href)
self['location']['assign'](location.href)
self['location']['replace'](location.href)
window.location = location
window.location = location.href
window.location = window.location
window.location = self.location
window.location = window.location.href
window.location = self.location.href
window.location = location['href']
window.location = window['location']
window.location = window['location'].href
window.location = window['location']['href']
window.location = window.location['href']
window.location = self['location']
window.location = self['location'].href
window.location = self['location']['href']
window.location = self.location['href']
location.assign(window.location)
location.replace(window.location)
window.location.assign(window.location)
window.location.replace(window.location)
self.location.assign(window.location)
self.location.replace(window.location)
location['assign'](window.location)
location['replace'](window.location)
window.location['assign'](window.location)
window.location['replace'](window.location)
window['location'].assign(window.location)
window['location'].replace(window.location)
window['location']['assign'](window.location)
window['location']['replace'](window.location)
self.location['assign'](window.location)
self.location['replace'](window.location)
self['location'].assign(window.location)
self['location'].replace(window.location)
self['location']['assign'](window.location)
self['location']['replace'](window.location)
self.location = location
self.location = location.href
self.location = window.location
self.location = self.location
self.location = window.location.href
self.location = self.location.href
self.location = location['href']
self.location = window['location']
self.location = window['location'].href
self.location = window['location']['href']
self.location = window.location['href']
self.location = self['location']
self.location = self['location'].href
self.location = self['location']['href']
self.location = self.location['href']
location.assign(self.location)
location.replace(self.location)
window.location.assign(self.location)
window.location.replace(self.location)
self.location.assign(self.location)
self.location.replace(self.location)
location['assign'](self.location)
location['replace'](self.location)
window.location['assign'](self.location)
window.location['replace'](self.location)
window['location'].assign(self.location)
window['location'].replace(self.location)
window['location']['assign'](self.location)
window['location']['replace'](self.location)
self.location['assign'](self.location)
self.location['replace'](self.location)
self['location'].assign(self.location)
self['location'].replace(self.location)
self['location']['assign'](self.location)
self['location']['replace'](self.location)
window.location.href = location
window.location.href = location.href
window.location.href = window.location
window.location.href = self.location
window.location.href = window.location.href
window.location.href = self.location.href
window.location.href = location['href']
window.location.href = window['location']
window.location.href = window['location'].href
window.location.href = window['location']['href']
window.location.href = window.location['href']
window.location.href = self['location']
window.location.href = self['location'].href
window.location.href = self['location']['href']
window.location.href = self.location['href']
location.assign(window.location.href)
location.replace(window.location.href)
window.location.assign(window.location.href)
window.location.replace(window.location.href)
self.location.assign(window.location.href)
self.location.replace(window.location.href)
location['assign'](window.location.href)
location['replace'](window.location.href)
window.location['assign'](window.location.href)
window.location['replace'](window.location.href)
window['location'].assign(window.location.href)
window['location'].replace(window.location.href)
window['location']['assign'](window.location.href)
window['location']['replace'](window.location.href)
self.location['assign'](window.location.href)
self.location['replace'](window.location.href)
self['location'].assign(window.location.href)
self['location'].replace(window.location.href)
self['location']['assign'](window.location.href)
self['location']['replace'](window.location.href)
self.location.href = location
self.location.href = location.href
self.location.href = window.location
self.location.href = self.location
self.location.href = window.location.href
self.location.href = self.location.href
self.location.href = location['href']
self.location.href = window['location']
self.location.href = window['location'].href
self.location.href = window['location']['href']
self.location.href = window.location['href']
self.location.href = self['location']
self.location.href = self['location'].href
self.location.href = self['location']['href']
self.location.href = self.location['href']
location.assign(self.location.href)
location.replace(self.location.href)
window.location.assign(self.location.href)
window.location.replace(self.location.href)
self.location.assign(self.location.href)
self.location.replace(self.location.href)
location['assign'](self.location.href)
location['replace'](self.location.href)
window.location['assign'](self.location.href)
window.location['replace'](self.location.href)
window['location'].assign(self.location.href)
window['location'].replace(self.location.href)
window['location']['assign'](self.location.href)
window['location']['replace'](self.location.href)
self.location['assign'](self.location.href)
self.location['replace'](self.location.href)
self['location'].assign(self.location.href)
self['location'].replace(self.location.href)
self['location']['assign'](self.location.href)
self['location']['replace'](self.location.href)
location['href'] = location
location['href'] = location.href
location['href'] = window.location
location['href'] = self.location
location['href'] = window.location.href
location['href'] = self.location.href
location['href'] = location['href']
location['href'] = window['location']
location['href'] = window['location'].href
location['href'] = window['location']['href']
location['href'] = window.location['href']
location['href'] = self['location']
location['href'] = self['location'].href
location['href'] = self['location']['href']
location['href'] = self.location['href']
location.assign(location['href'])
location.replace(location['href'])
window.location.assign(location['href'])
window.location.replace(location['href'])
self.location.assign(location['href'])
self.location.replace(location['href'])
location['assign'](location['href'])
location['replace'](location['href'])
window.location['assign'](location['href'])
window.location['replace'](location['href'])
window['location'].assign(location['href'])
window['location'].replace(location['href'])
window['location']['assign'](location['href'])
window['location']['replace'](location['href'])
self.location['assign'](location['href'])
self.location['replace'](location['href'])
self['location'].assign(location['href'])
self['location'].replace(location['href'])
self['location']['assign'](location['href'])
self['location']['replace'](location['href'])
window['location'] = location
window['location'] = location.href
window['location'] = window.location
window['location'] = self.location
window['location'] = window.location.href
window['location'] = self.location.href
window['location'] = location['href']
window['location'] = window['location']
window['location'] = window['location'].href
window['location'] = window['location']['href']
window['location'] = window.location['href']
window['location'] = self['location']
window['location'] = self['location'].href
window['location'] = self['location']['href']
window['location'] = self.location['href']
location.assign(window['location'])
location.replace(window['location'])
window.location.assign(window['location'])
window.location.replace(window['location'])
self.location.assign(window['location'])
self.location.replace(window['location'])
location['assign'](window['location'])
location['replace'](window['location'])
window.location['assign'](window['location'])
window.location['replace'](window['location'])
window['location'].assign(window['location'])
window['location'].replace(window['location'])
window['location']['assign'](window['location'])
window['location']['replace'](window['location'])
self.location['assign'](window['location'])
self.location['replace'](window['location'])
self['location'].assign(window['location'])
self['location'].replace(window['location'])
self['location']['assign'](window['location'])
self['location']['replace'](window['location'])
window['location'].href = location
window['location'].href = location.href
window['location'].href = window.location
window['location'].href = self.location
window['location'].href = window.location.href
window['location'].href = self.location.href
window['location'].href = location['href']
window['location'].href = window['location']
window['location'].href = window['location'].href
window['location'].href = window['location']['href']
window['location'].href = window.location['href']
window['location'].href = self['location']
window['location'].href = self['location'].href
window['location'].href = self['location']['href']
window['location'].href = self.location['href']
location.assign(window['location'].href)
location.replace(window['location'].href)
window.location.assign(window['location'].href)
window.location.replace(window['location'].href)
self.location.assign(window['location'].href)
self.location.replace(window['location'].href)
location['assign'](window['location'].href)
location['replace'](window['location'].href)
window.location['assign'](window['location'].href)
window.location['replace'](window['location'].href)
window['location'].assign(window['location'].href)
window['location'].replace(window['location'].href)
window['location']['assign'](window['location'].href)
window['location']['replace'](window['location'].href)
self.location['assign'](window['location'].href)
self.location['replace'](window['location'].href)
self['location'].assign(window['location'].href)
self['location'].replace(window['location'].href)
self['location']['assign'](window['location'].href)
self['location']['replace'](window['location'].href)
window['location']['href'] = location
window['location']['href'] = location.href
window['location']['href'] = window.location
window['location']['href'] = self.location
window['location']['href'] = window.location.href
window['location']['href'] = self.location.href
window['location']['href'] = location['href']
window['location']['href'] = window['location']
window['location']['href'] = window['location'].href
window['location']['href'] = window['location']['href']
window['location']['href'] = window.location['href']
window['location']['href'] = self['location']
window['location']['href'] = self['location'].href
window['location']['href'] = self['location']['href']
window['location']['href'] = self.location['href']
location.assign(window['location']['href'])
location.replace(window['location']['href'])
window.location.assign(window['location']['href'])
window.location.replace(window['location']['href'])
self.location.assign(window['location']['href'])
self.location.replace(window['location']['href'])
location['assign'](window['location']['href'])
location['replace'](window['location']['href'])
window.location['assign'](window['location']['href'])
window.location['replace'](window['location']['href'])
window['location'].assign(window['location']['href'])
window['location'].replace(window['location']['href'])
window['location']['assign'](window['location']['href'])
window['location']['replace'](window['location']['href'])
self.location['assign'](window['location']['href'])
self.location['replace'](window['location']['href'])
self['location'].assign(window['location']['href'])
self['location'].replace(window['location']['href'])
self['location']['assign'](window['location']['href'])
self['location']['replace'](window['location']['href'])
window.location['href'] = location
window.location['href'] = location.href
window.location['href'] = window.location
window.location['href'] = self.location
window.location['href'] = window.location.href
window.location['href'] = self.location.href
window.location['href'] = location['href']
window.location['href'] = window['location']
window.location['href'] = window['location'].href
window.location['href'] = window['location']['href']
window.location['href'] = window.location['href']
window.location['href'] = self['location']
window.location['href'] = self['location'].href
window.location['href'] = self['location']['href']
window.location['href'] = self.location['href']
location.assign(window.location['href'])
location.replace(window.location['href'])
window.location.assign(window.location['href'])
window.location.replace(window.location['href'])
self.location.assign(window.location['href'])
self.location.replace(window.location['href'])
location['assign'](window.location['href'])
location['replace'](window.location['href'])
window.location['assign'](window.location['href'])
window.location['replace'](window.location['href'])
window['location'].assign(window.location['href'])
window['location'].replace(window.location['href'])
window['location']['assign'](window.location['href'])
window['location']['replace'](window.location['href'])
self.location['assign'](window.location['href'])
self.location['replace'](window.location['href'])
self['location'].assign(window.location['href'])
self['location'].replace(window.location['href'])
self['location']['assign'](window.location['href'])
self['location']['replace'](window.location['href'])
self['location'] = location
self['location'] = location.href
self['location'] = window.location
self['location'] = self.location
self['location'] = window.location.href
self['location'] = self.location.href
self['location'] = location['href']
self['location'] = window['location']
self['location'] = window['location'].href
self['location'] = window['location']['href']
self['location'] = window.location['href']
self['location'] = self['location']
self['location'] = self['location'].href
self['location'] = self['location']['href']
self['location'] = self.location['href']
location.assign(self['location'])
location.replace(self['location'])
window.location.assign(self['location'])
window.location.replace(self['location'])
self.location.assign(self['location'])
self.location.replace(self['location'])
location['assign'](self['location'])
location['replace'](self['location'])
window.location['assign'](self['location'])
window.location['replace'](self['location'])
window['location'].assign(self['location'])
window['location'].replace(self['location'])
window['location']['assign'](self['location'])
window['location']['replace'](self['location'])
self.location['assign'](self['location'])
self.location['replace'](self['location'])
self['location'].assign(self['location'])
self['location'].replace(self['location'])
self['location']['assign'](self['location'])
self['location']['replace'](self['location'])
self['location'].href = location
self['location'].href = location.href
self['location'].href = window.location
self['location'].href = self.location
self['location'].href = window.location.href
self['location'].href = self.location.href
self['location'].href = location['href']
self['location'].href = window['location']
self['location'].href = window['location'].href
self['location'].href = window['location']['href']
self['location'].href = window.location['href']
self['location'].href = self['location']
self['location'].href = self['location'].href
self['location'].href = self['location']['href']
self['location'].href = self.location['href']
location.assign(self['location'].href)
location.replace(self['location'].href)
window.location.assign(self['location'].href)
window.location.replace(self['location'].href)
self.location.assign(self['location'].href)
self.location.replace(self['location'].href)
location['assign'](self['location'].href)
location['replace'](self['location'].href)
window.location['assign'](self['location'].href)
window.location['replace'](self['location'].href)
window['location'].assign(self['location'].href)
window['location'].replace(self['location'].href)
window['location']['assign'](self['location'].href)
window['location']['replace'](self['location'].href)
self.location['assign'](self['location'].href)
self.location['replace'](self['location'].href)
self['location'].assign(self['location'].href)
self['location'].replace(self['location'].href)
self['location']['assign'](self['location'].href)
self['location']['replace'](self['location'].href)
self['location']['href'] = location
self['location']['href'] = location.href
self['location']['href'] = window.location
self['location']['href'] = self.location
self['location']['href'] = window.location.href
self['location']['href'] = self.location.href
self['location']['href'] = location['href']
self['location']['href'] = window['location']
self['location']['href'] = window['location'].href
self['location']['href'] = window['location']['href']
self['location']['href'] = window.location['href']
self['location']['href'] = self['location']
self['location']['href'] = self['location'].href
self['location']['href'] = self['location']['href']
self['location']['href'] = self.location['href']
location.assign(self['location']['href'])
location.replace(self['location']['href'])
window.location.assign(self['location']['href'])
window.location.replace(self['location']['href'])
self.location.assign(self['location']['href'])
self.location.replace(self['location']['href'])
location['assign'](self['location']['href'])
location['replace'](self['location']['href'])
window.location['assign'](self['location']['href'])
window.location['replace'](self['location']['href'])
window['location'].assign(self['location']['href'])
window['location'].replace(self['location']['href'])
window['location']['assign'](self['location']['href'])
window['location']['replace'](self['location']['href'])
self.location['assign'](self['location']['href'])
self.location['replace'](self['location']['href'])
self['location'].assign(self['location']['href'])
self['location'].replace(self['location']['href'])
self['location']['assign'](self['location']['href'])
self['location']['replace'](self['location']['href'])
self.location['href'] = location
self.location['href'] = location.href
self.location['href'] = window.location
self.location['href'] = self.location
self.location['href'] = window.location.href
self.location['href'] = self.location.href
self.location['href'] = location['href']
self.location['href'] = window['location']
self.location['href'] = window['location'].href
self.location['href'] = window['location']['href']
self.location['href'] = window.location['href']
self.location['href'] = self['location']
self.location['href'] = self['location'].href
self.location['href'] = self['location']['href']
self.location['href'] = self.location['href']
location.assign(self.location['href'])
location.replace(self.location['href'])
window.location.assign(self.location['href'])
window.location.replace(self.location['href'])
self.location.assign(self.location['href'])
self.location.replace(self.location['href'])
location['assign'](self.location['href'])
location['replace'](self.location['href'])
window.location['assign'](self.location['href'])
window.location['replace'](self.location['href'])
window['location'].assign(self.location['href'])
window['location'].replace(self.location['href'])
window['location']['assign'](self.location['href'])
window['location']['replace'](self.location['href'])
self.location['assign'](self.location['href'])
self.location['replace'](self.location['href'])
self['location'].assign(self.location['href'])
self['location'].replace(self.location['href'])
self['location']['assign'](self.location['href'])
self['location']['replace'](self.location['href'])
location.reload()
location['reload']()
window.location.reload()
window['location'].reload()
window.location['reload']()
window['location']['reload']()
self.location.reload()
self['location'].reload()
self.location['reload']()
self['location']['reload']()
```

One of those is bound to work where `location.reload();` doesn't.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: The prove that JavaScript is the most weirdest script language...

Answer (score 1):

The architecture of most of JS mobile applications (Hybrid Mobile Applications) is based on the concept of single page application.

As mentioned in Building Hybrid Android Apps with Java and JavaScript Book
by Nizamettin Gok; Nitin Khanna

> These apps persistently run the same page with different views or
>   content, but without reloading or navigating away to another resource.This is achieved by separating the data from the presentation layer and relies heavily on JavaScript. SPA architecture uses the fragment identifier, which is introduced by a hashtag (#) in the URL location, followed by an anchor identifier to point to an element in the HTML document. For example, if your website URL looks like this http://oreilly.com/index.html#article, The fragment article refers to an HTML element with an id="article" attribute in the index.html document.

So the idea of reloading the page may not be the best choice but however you can overcome this problem using the helpers provided on your framework. Here are some examples:

JQuery Mobile: [jQuery Mobile Page refresh mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663078/jquery-mobile-page-refresh-mechanism)

Cordova: [How to reload page on a Cordova project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884793/how-to-reload-page-on-a-cordova-project)

Ionic(angularJS): [Reloading current state - refresh data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714655/reloading-current-state-refresh-data)

You can also update the view using the data binding methods and avoid reloading the page.

Comment: What if your app needs to be reloaded because some .js files have been updated on the server?