# location.reload() not working properly in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, django, jquery-mobile

location.reload() not working properly in mobile devices...

location.reload() is working fine on desktop browsers but not working on mobile browsers (android)...

i work in Django selected fileds that come from  ajax selections of modelchoicefields querysets  are lost after window.location.reload().  everthing works fine in desktops but not in mobile devices.

what should i change or add???

you can see the difference in added image...[difference between desktop and mobile device working..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnhzo.jpg)

code is a standart ajax call for Django to dynamically select fields that are related to the previous selection...

```
<script>
    function prosecFunction() {
        var response = '';
        var selected = document.getElementById("id_proje").value;
        console.log(selected);
        $.ajax({
          url : "demirbas_ariza_listesi/",
          type : "GET",
          dataType: "text",
          data : {
            'selected' : selected,
              },
          success: function() {
              window.location.reload();
               },
          failure: function() {
              alert("hata var....veri aktarılamadı...");
              }
          });  /* ajax kapa...*/
    }
  </script>

 <script>
```

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267621/location-reload-on-mobile-js-app

Answer (score -1):

Try `document.location.reload(true);` instead of `window.location.reload();`

```
success: function(data){    

    document.location.reload(true);         

}
```

Comment: it's not working for me on android in custom webview-browser